# How to get a dictionary within a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data in a text file in the format given below:-

```
Monday     Maths   100  95  65  32  23  45  77  54  78  88  45  67  89
Tuesday    Science 45   53  76  78  54  78  34  99  55  100 45  56 78
Wednesday  English 43   45  56  76  98  34  65  34  45  67  76  34  98
```

I want to write python code which will produce an output something like this:-

```
{
'monday': {'maths': [100  95  65  32  23  45  77  54  78  88  45  67  89}, 
'tuesday': {'Science':45   53  76  78  54  78  34  99  55  100 45  56 78}, 
'Wednesday': {'English': 43   45  56  76  98  34  65  34  45  67  76  34  98}
}
```

**Here is the snippet:**

```
fo = open('C:\\Users\\aman\\Documents\\dataVal.txt','r')
data = fo.readlines()

mydict = {}
li = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split('\t')
    timeKey = row[0]
    type = row[1]
    if mydict.has_key(timeKey):
        li = mydict[timeKey]
        li.append(type)
        mydict[timeKey] = li
    else:
        li = []
        li.append(type)
        mydict[timeKey] = li
print mydict
```

This gives me the output like:-

{'Monday': ['Maths', 'Science', 'English']}

But I want the output which is mentioned above.

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try something that didn't work? Post your attempt so people can help you. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: inside monday: {} or [] ?? should be dictionary and maths should be the key right.

Comment: Yes I want Monday to be the key and Maths to be its value and then Maths to be the key and the marks to be its values. Similarly, tuesday to be the key and science to be its value and then science to be the key and the marks to be its values and same for wednesday. So using my code I get monday as the key and maths, science and english as its values but now I also want the marks added as values of maths, science and english respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my solution:**

```
  dic = dict()
  with open('txt', 'r') as fh:
     for l in fh.readlines():
          try:
              lines = l.split()
              day, sub, num = lines[0], lines[1], [int(x) for x in lines[2:]]
              dic.setdefault(day, {})
              dic[day][sub] = num
          except Exception as er:
              print er
  print dic
```

Output:

```
 {'Tuesday': {'Science': [45, 53, 76, 78, 54, 78, 34, 99, 55, 100, 45, 56, 78]}, 
  'Wednesday': {'English': [43, 45, 56, 76, 98, 34, 65, 34, 45, 67, 76, 34, 98]},
  'Monday':  {'Maths': [100, 95, 65, 32, 23, 45, 77, 54, 78, 88, 45, 67, 89]}}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry one more question. Lets suppose instead of Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday I have time say 16:00, 17:00 and 18:00 respectively. If this would be the case, then it throws an error saying invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:00:00'. invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:00:00'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:00:00'
{}

Comment: You may need to change the data structure, lets see.

Comment: Or please put in question i ll change accordingly

Comment: I have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597108/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-160000