# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:00:00'

Tags: python-2.7

```
dic = dict()
with open('C:\\Users\\aman\\Documents\\dataVal.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for l in fh.readlines():
        try:
            lines = l.split()
            date, sub, num = lines[0], lines[1], [int(x) for x in lines[2:]]
            dic.setdefault(date, {})
            dic[date][sub] = num
        except Exception as er:
            print er
print dic
```

Can someone Help?
Its giving me an error saying invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16:00:00' .How to get rid of it? Just for your information '16:00:00' is the first column in the table in the txt file

```
16:00:00     Maths   100  95  65  32  23  45  77  54  78  88  45  67  89
17:00:00    Science 45   53  76  78  54  78  34  99  55  100 45  56 78
18:00:00  English 43   45  56  76  98  34  65  34  45  67  76  34  98
```

Comment: Please put up the line you are parsing and the error. BTW please change int(x) to str(x) if you ve string type also.

Comment: and how the output you want ? 'time as key'

Comment: can you paste the error you got, '16:00:00' can be used as string so your code should work

Comment: Ok here, lets confirm your error first. i din't see any error with your code, except the indentation i fixed.

Comment: The solution snippet that you added. it worked perfect. Thanks alot.You r a genius.

Comment: you mean by changing int() to str() ? Because some one is down voting me :)

Comment: Dont worry mate I voted you up and Thanks alot once again

Comment: Hey man! Can you help me with another similar question with a slight change?

Comment: ya sure, update in question as Edit 2.

Comment: Hey mate check this out....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601984/how-to-create-a-dictionary-from-a-dictionary-in-python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I changed int(x) to str(x), could you please try. if thats the error.**

```
dic = dict()
with open('C:\\Users\\aman\\Documents\\dataVal.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for l in fh.readlines():
        try:
            lines = l.split()
            date, sub, num = lines[0], lines[1], [str(x) for x in lines[2:]]
            dic.setdefault(date, {})
            dic[date][sub] = num
        except Exception as er:
            print er
print dic
```

Output:

```
 {'17:00:00': {'Science': ['45', '53', '76', '78', '54', '78', '34', '99', '55', '100', '45', '56', '78']}, 
  '18:00:00': {'English': ['43', '45', '56', '76', '98', '34', '65', '34', '45', '67', '76', '34', '98']}, 
  '16:00:00': {'Maths': ['100', '95', '65', '32', '23', '45', '77', '54', '78', '88', '45', '67', '89']}}
```

Comment: ah sorry about that, i changed the indentation for `try` and `except` check now