# How to create a dictionary from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
Date        Subject     Maths  Science English French  Spanish German
16:00:00    Uploaded      100    95      65      32      23      45 
17:00:00    Unknown        45    53      76      78      54      78  
18:00:00    Captured       43    45      56      76      98      34 

Date        BoardType     Maths  Science English French  Spanish German
16:00:00     CBSE          50     95      65      32      23      45 
17:00:00     NTSE          45     53      76      78      54      78  
18:00:00     YTTB         100     45      56      76      98      34
```

I have these 2 tables in my text file called dataVal.txt.

I want the output to be like:-

'Subject':'Uploaded':'16:00:00':''Maths':'100', Science::95....something like this.
Basically 'Subject' is the main key for the first table which which has 'Uploaded' as its value and then 'Uploaded' becomes the key which has '16:00:00' as its value and then this becomes the key and has Maths, science, english and so on as its values which furthur have their own values as 100, 95,65 and so on.

```
dic = dict()
with open('C:\\Users\\aman.seth\\Documents\\dataVal.txt','r') as fh:
    for l in fh.readlines():
        try:
            lines = l.split('\t')
            date, sub, num = lines[0], lines[1], [str(x) for x in lines[2:]]
            dic.setdefault(sub, {})
            dic[sub][date] = num
        except Exception as er:
            print er
print dic
```

This is what I have done so far but it is not enough and accurate I guess.

Comment: I don't think the example you give is really what you want to result to look like... you open a lot more `{` curly braces than you close!

Comment: I have edited it. Please check it out. Since I am not able to generate the right output I am unable to show what exactly I want but I have provided a description. Please go through it and let me know if you still dont understand

Comment: are you sure...? that's a really odd data structure to use. It would make more sense to turn the table into a list of dicts, where each row in the table is a dict and the keys of the dict are the column headings

Comment: Can you please provide the code for it so that I can try to run it and see the output and relate it to mine? Thank you

Comment: is it possible your `dataVal.txt` file is tab-delimited? in that case you could use [python's csv reader module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do the parsing for you

Comment: how would you differentiate the two table.

Comment: Thats what I am unable to figure out mate. Thats why asked for your help. Do you have any solution in mind?

Comment: Ok shall we differntiate the two table as 'Subject' and 'BoardType'

Comment: Yess we should. Hey what if we put this 'Subject' and 'BoardType' in a list first and then run a for loop or something?

Comment: And one more thing, before proceeding with this. I want 'Maths','Science','English'...as seprate keys and the marks as their values. Is it possible to make changes to this code and do this??

Comment: you can try something like this, first match the header, based on the heard match, you can create a key inside a dict['Subject'] or dic['BoardType'] then fill inside it as like before

Comment: Mate I am new to this language. I can think of ideas but cant implement them. Can you help me with this. I will really appreciate that seriously:)

Comment: And we can try this later. Please help me out in making 'Maths', 'Science'...all these subjects as sperate keys and their respective marks as their values. something like 'Maths':'100', 'Science':'95', 'English':'67'...Like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46934/discussion-between-aman-and-yopy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and lets fixed:

```
import re

dic = dict()

with open('txt', 'r') as fh:
    memory = None
    for line in fh.readlines():
        lines = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.split():
            try:
                match = re.search('(BoardType|Subject)', line)
                if match:
                    memory = match.group(1)
                    dic.setdefault(memory, {})
                    header = line.split()
                    mark_index = header[2:]
                else:
                    mark_dict = dict()
                    lines = [ x for x in line.split(' ') if x]
                    date, sub, num = lines[0], lines[1], [str(x) for x in lines[2:]]
                    dic[memory].setdefault(sub, {})
                    mark = dict(zip(mark_index, num))
                    dic[memory][sub][date] = mark
            except Exception as error:
                print 'Error: ', error
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'BoardType': {'CBSE': {'16:00:00': {'English': '65',
                                     'French': '32',
                                     'German': '45',
                                     'Maths': '50',
                                     'Science': '95',
                                     'Spanish': '23'}},
               'NTSE': {'17:00:00': {'English': '76',
                                     'French': '78',
                                     'German': '78',
                                     'Maths': '45',
                                     'Science': '53',
                                     'Spanish': '54'}},
               'YTTB': {'18:00:00': {'English': '56',
                                     'French': '76',
                                     'German': '34',
                                     'Maths': '100',
                                     'Science': '45',
                                     'Spanish': '98'}}},
 'Subject': {'Captured': {'18:00:00': {'English': '56',
                                       'French': '76',
                                       'German': '34\n',
                                       'Maths': '43',
                                       'Science': '45',
                                       'Spanish': '98'}},
             'Unknown': {'17:00:00': {'English': '76',
                                      'French': '78',
                                      'German': '78\n',
                                      'Maths': '45',
                                      'Science': '53',
                                      'Spanish': '54'}},
             'Uploaded': {'16:00:00': {'English': '65',
                                       'French': '32',
                                       'German': '45\n',
                                       'Maths': '100',
                                       'Science': '95',
                                       'Spanish': '23'}}}}
```

Comment: how is that look, if that doesn't work ping me on chat

Comment: Mate you are truly a genius. Thanks alot man. I know this is way too much but just a little bit of more help pleaseeee

Comment: hey mate, r u there. Need ur help. I left u a couple of messages on the chat. Not sure whether u have received them yet or not. Anyways, I need ur help yet again. Would really appreciate if u get back. Thanks!:)